# Spring Boot - Multiple filter chains from dependencies

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm having a following scenario with Spring modules A and B:

- **module A** - Spring module having security setup for single sign on, using @EnableOAuth2Sso, @EnableWebSecurity(debug = true) and @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
- **module B** - Spring Boot application, has A as dependency , doesn't use any security configuration.

When I launch B, I get 2 Filter chains , first comes from module A and it's used for SSO, second comes from module B and is redundant:

- o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: AnyRequestMatcher@1, [WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@1407b93f, SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@38241615, OAuth2ClientContextFilter@31a8c3a3, HeaderWriterFilter@6bf2ecbb, LogoutFilter@6cc022ac, OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter@5aff8207, BasicAuthenticationFilter@42eaf47f, RequestCacheAwareFilter@42fc744, SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@6eeb15f9, AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@6a5a99d9, SessionManagementFilter@5955568, ExceptionTranslationFilter@74ec4df3, FilterSecurityInterceptor@6a577564]
- o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: AnyRequestMatcher@1, [WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@138110f8, SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@6278371a, HeaderWriterFilter@6b61a4b0, LogoutFilter@30623109, RequestCacheAwareFilter@c6a1be2, SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@6a486afb, AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@4fe8ac61, SessionManagementFilter@5c00de0d, ExceptionTranslationFilter@32db94fb]

**Problems:**

- how can I disable default filter chain that has no use?
- debug flag of module A - @EnableWebSecurity(debug = true) , is ignored when running module B and I'm not able to debug the security setup
- is it possible to "extend" the chain of A and add more filters in B ?

Comment: With `@EnableWebSecurity` the Spring Boot's default configuration should be disabled. To see what really happens you have to configure Spring Security log with `DEBUG` level.

Comment: that's the behaviour I've expected as well, but it's not what happens...
module A referenced from B using @ComponentScan, maybe it somehow affects the whole scenario.. still investigating it...

Answer (score 0):

This is old but I had the same issue and solved it by adding the `@EnableWebSecurity` annotation to module A and this to the module B:s `@SpringBootApplication`:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
```

If you want to know why then google "SecurityAutoConfiguration" for more information about Springs security default behaviour.